# addColumn() in grid magento2?

Tags: magento2, grid

in Gird magento2

```
 $this->addColumn(
        'edit',
        [
            'header' => __('Edit'),
            'type' => 'action',
            'getter' => 'getId',
            'actions' => [
                [
                    'caption' => __('Edit'),
                    'url' => [
                        'base' => '*/*/edit',
                        'params' => ['store' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('store')]
                    ],
                    'field' => 'id'
                ]
            ],
            'filter' => false,
            'sortable' => false,
            'index' => 'stores',
            'header_css_class' => 'col-action',
            'column_css_class' => 'col-action'
        ]
    );
```

i want modifie it like [image]

Answer (score 2):

you cannot have a column like that unless you create your grid using the ui components. Here is an example from the core: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Cms/view/adminhtml/ui_component/cms_page_listing.xml.  The column in question is this one: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Cms/view/adminhtml/ui_component/cms_page_listing.xml#L325

You will need a class like this: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Cms/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/PageActions.php